# Array.prototype.includes() wildcard options?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which filters an array by tags (specifically 2 tags). It works well with word strings but I would like to add the ability to use some sort of wildcard. For example to filter all tags that start with `"-"` (my attempt at grouping the tags). Using this string here doesn't work. I have also tried using a regular expression eg. `/^-/` but that doesn't work either.

I have discovered that `Array.prototype.includes()` differs from `String.prototype.includes()` in that it only captures whole "words" so that probably explains why it's not working but was I wondering if there was some way to do this?

```js
var cards = [
  {
    cardId: 1001,
    tags: ["_easy", "-casual"],
    videoId: "rO5BVRK6KMo",
  },
  {
    cardId: 1002,
    tags: ["_hard", "-polite"],
    videoId: "qK--SAlGD0Q",
  }
]

var ReviewtagFilter = function() {
  let reviewsTagged = [];
  let tagLevel = "_easy";  
  let tagTopic = "-casual"; //***"-" doesn't work to get -casual & "-polite"
  //console.log("tagLevel: ", tagLevel + "tagTopic" , tagTopic)

  reviewsTagged = cards.filter(
    data => data.tags.includes(tagLevel) && data.tags.includes(tagTopic)
  );
  console.log(reviewsTagged)
};
ReviewtagFilter();
```

Comment: Sounds like you need [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) not `includes`

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean instead of filter()?

Comment: Why instead of `filter`? Using `includes` returns a boolean you use when filtering and `filter` itself returns an array. `some` also returns a boolean but you include custom functionality for what is matched. You can trivially re-create `arr.includes(something)` by doing `arr.some(item => item == something)`. But you need *different* logic than a straight match, so you can implement that logic in the predicate given to `some`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, you cannot use regex with `Array.includes()`. The simplest way would be to use a `some()` or `every()` (depending on what do you want to achieve) instead:

```js
var ReviewtagFilter = function() {
  let reviewsTagged = [];
  let tagLevel = "_easy";  
  let tagTopic = /^-/; 

  reviewsTagged = cards.filter(
    data => data.some(tag => tag.match(tagTopic)) && data.tags.includes(tagLevel)
  );
  console.log(reviewsTagged)
};
```